# Decrease the length of chrome in output of ps command

Tags: google-chrome

When I do `ps axuww|grep -i chrome`, the length of chrome is too long

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/34.0.1847.131/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper --type=renderer --lang=ja --force-fieldtrials=AutocompleteDynamicTrial_2/DefaultControl_R2_Stable/ChromeSuggestions/Default/EmbeddedSearch/Group7 pct:10g stable:pp1 use_cacheable_ntp:1 espv:210 suppress_on_srp:1/ExtensionInstallVerification/None/GoogleNow/DisabledViaNoRichNotifications/OmniboxBundledExperimentV1/StandardR3/Prerender/PrerenderEnabled/PrerenderFromOmnibox/OmniboxPrerenderEnabled/PrerenderLocalPredictorSpec/LocalPredictor=Disabled/QUIC/Disabled/SettingsEnforcement/no_enforcement/Test0PercentDefault/group_01/UMA-Dynamic-Binary-Uniformity-Trial/default/UMA-Dynamic-Uniformity-Trial/Group3/UMA-Population-Restrict/normal/UMA-Session-Randomized-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_07/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-1-Percent/group_29/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-10-Percent/group_09/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-100-Percent/group_01/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-20-Percent/group_02/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_15/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/default/ --extension-process --renderer-print-preview --enable-threaded-compositing --enable-deadline-scheduling --disable-accelerated-video-decode --enable-software-compositing --channel=825.605.1417878444
```

Is it possible to reduce it?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Something like `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/34.0.1847.131/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper`, no parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's available, you can use the `cut` command to split the line at the first `-`.

Example: `ps axuww|grep -i chrome | cut -d'-' -f1`

`-d` specifies the delimiter and `-f` specifies the field(s) to return.